# UICollectionView : visible cell count

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

When i print out the visible cell count in my UICollectionView and the array count it's off by one. The visible cell count is lower. Any ideas?

```
 NSLog(@"visibleCellscount %d",self.collectionView.visibleCells.count);   (visibleCellscount 2)
 NSLog(@"birdscount %d",self.birds.count);   (birdscount 3)
```

Comment: May be only 2 cells are visible?

Comment: What if you get "self.collectionView.cells.count"?  What does it return?  If it's 3 then i'd agree with ACB, only 2 are visible.

Comment: I see 3. And when i try "self.collectionView.cells.count" it gives me an error that says cell are not a property of type UICollectionView.

Comment: @BDGapps, How many cells are visible at a time in the screen? Can you see all 3 at a time?